# How to Implement Application Insights Telemetry on ASP.NET 4.7.1 that uses Appsettings.json?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights, telemetry

How can I configure application insights telemetry for an asp.net framework 4.7.1 web application that uses `appsettings.json` configuration files? I tried checking the Microsoft documentation but it just shows setup for ASP.NET apps that use xml-based configuration.

EDIT: Here is the part of the `Startup.cs` file that shows I am using `appsettings.json`.

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }
```

Comment: .Net Framework code doesn't use appsettings.json files unless you have manual code. How are you reading this file?

Comment: @gunr2171 I am using `ConfigurationBuilder` class in the constructor of my `Startup.cs` file to read the `appsettings.json` file

Answer (score 1):

**SCENARIO - 1**

This works in case of .net framework 4.7.1 web application which have no auto generated `appsettings.json` file.

1. Navigate to your **Project** > **Add Application Insights Telemetry** > **Application Insights Sdk (local)** > **Next** > **Finish** > **Close**
2. In `applicationinsights.config` file, while Adding Application Insights automatically we need to add instrumentation key to  `ApplicationInsights.config`  before closing the  `</ApplicationInsights>`  tag file.

   ```cs
   <InstrumentationKey>"your-instrumentation-key-goes-here"</InstrumentationKey>
   ```

   [image]
3. And then update each  `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights`  NuGet package to the latest stable release by navigating to  **Project**  >  **Manage NuGet Packages**  >  **Updates**.

If Adding Application Insights Automatically isn't working, then you can try manually from  [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net#add-application-insights-manually).

**REFERENCE :**  [Configure monitoring for ASP.NET with Azure Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net#add-application-insights-automatically)

---

**SCENARIO - 2**

You can have application Insights configuration set from your appsettings.json file when you have one in your project

1. Navigate to your appsettings.json file and add your instrumentation key for your application Insights like mentioned inthe below reference.
   [image]
2. Application Insights comes in the form of a Nuget package. Review the **.csproj** file of the web project and look for the Application Insights package added.
   [image]
3. Now navigate to your startup.cs project and add **services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);** to your **ConfigureServices** method.

   [image]
4. Navigate to **Configure**  method and add

   ```
   app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();
   app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();
   ```

   [image]

**REFERENCE :** [Monitoring Applications using Application Insights](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vsts/monitor/#:%7E:text=%20Exercise%204%3A%20Adding%20Application%20Insights%20to%20New,Open%20_Layout.cshtml%20and%20check%20the%20part...%20More%20)